# Not receiving push notifications on iOS 7 ( Parse )

Tags: xcode, ios7, push-notification, parse-platform

I put this line in AppDelegate ( didFinishedLaunching ).

```
[Parse setApplicationId:@"MYAPP" clientKey:@"MYKEY"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]  registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:  (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert )];
```

and this into "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken

```
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    currentInstallation.channels = @[@"global"];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

It says "device registered successfully". No errors.

On first application launch I get "Do you want to receive remote notifications". 
When I send PN from Parse it says "Sent successful", but nothing happens on device. ( foreground, closed, whatever ). 
I already tried to make a lot of new certificates/provisionprofiles/appIds... still nothing. ( and removing previous ones in DevCenter and on iPhone itself ). In Parse settings pushes are enabled and P12 file is uploaded.
Who already faced problem like this one?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I recreated certificates and mobile provision files a lot times with different order.

Comment: i solved it! You need the code still? @Neko Code